# My simple CUDA wrapper and Makefile do not work

Tags: c, cuda, makefile, openmp, nvcc

this is my first post here - so pelase be patient with me. I am currently trying to figure out how to compile a simple project that contains normal *.c files and for simplicity one *.cu file. Obviously I want to use *nvcc* to do that I have got two "libs" that should basically do the same but one relies on OMP and the other one on CUDA. But after about one day of browsing the web and crawling through stackoverflow I am completely stuck. Here is what I got:

My source/main.c:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "../include/mylib_omp.h"
#include "../include/mylib_cuda.h"

int main(){

    myfunc_CUDA(3.0,4);

    return 0;
}
```

My include/mylib_omp.h:

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_OMP_H__
#define __MYLIB_OMP_H__

#include <omp.h>

void myfunc_OMP(float, int);

#endif
```

My include/mylib_cuda.h:

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_CUDA_H__
#define __MYLIB_CUDA_H__

#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>

void myfunc_CUDA(float, int);

#endif
```

My source/mylib_omp.c:

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_OMP_C__
#define __MYLIB_OMP_C__

#include "../include/mylib_omp.h"

void myfunc_OMP(float, int){
    int i;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            int k = 0;
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

My source/mylib_cuda.cu

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_CUDA_CU__
#define __MYLIB_CUDA_CU__

extern "C"{
#include "../include/mylib_cuda.h"
}

extern "C"
void myfunc_CUDA(float a, int b){
    float* i;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &i,5*sizeof(float));
}

#endif
```

And finally my Makefile:

```
CC = nvcc
OUT = main

INCL_DIR = -I include
SOUR_DIR = sources

SOURCES =   ${SOUR_DIR}/main.c \
        ${SOUR_DIR}/mylib_omp.c \

CUDA_SOURCES =  ${SOUR_DIR}/mylib_cuda.cu 

H_FILES =   ${wildcard ${INCL_DIR}/*.h}

OBJECTS = ${SOURCES:.c=.o}
NVOBJECTS = ${CUDA_SOURCES:.cu=.o}

CFLAGS = -O3

NVCCFLAGS = -arch=sm_12 -ccbin=g++-4.4 -Xcompiler -openmp -x c++

LFLAGS = -lm -lcuda

INCLUDES = -I/opt/cuda/include
LIBS = -L/opt/cuda/lib64

${OUT}: ${OBJECTS} ${NVOBJECTS}
    $(CC) $(INCL_DIR) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^ 

$(SOUR_DIR)/%.o : $(SOUR_DIR)/%.cu $(H_FILES)
    $(CC) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(INCL_DIR) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS) -c -o $@ $<

$(SOUR_DIR)/%.o : $(SOUR_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(INCL_DIR) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS) -c -o $@ $<



clean :
    rm -f ${OBJECTS} ${NVOBJECTS} $(OUT)
```

Sorry for the many files, but this is basically as short as it gets. I just yesterday figured out how to deal with makefiles since I have never actually tried to work on a bigger project in any language. So now for the problem. When I run make the following happens:

```
[seb@seb-desktop make_cuda]$ make clean
rm -f sources/main.o sources/mylib_omp.o sources/mylib_cuda.o main
[seb@seb-desktop make_cuda]$ make
nvcc -arch=sm_12 -ccbin=g++-4.4 -Xcompiler -openmp -x c++ -I include -I/opt/cuda/include -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -c -o sources/main.o sources/main.c
nvcc -arch=sm_12 -ccbin=g++-4.4 -Xcompiler -openmp -x c++ -I include -I/opt/cuda/include -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -c -o sources/mylib_omp.o sources/mylib_omp.c
nvcc -arch=sm_12 -ccbin=g++-4.4 -Xcompiler -openmp -x c++ -I include -I/opt/cuda/include -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -c -o sources/mylib_cuda.o sources/mylib_cuda.cu
nvcc -I include -I/opt/cuda/include -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -O3 -lm -lcuda -o main sources/main.o sources/mylib_omp.o sources/mylib_cuda.o 
sources/main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `myfunc_CUDA(float, int)'
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Any help will be gladly appreciated with a hug and a ticket to the very first ride on my time machine! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your `main.c` file is expecting a c++ linkable entry point to `myfunc_CUDA` but your `mylib_cuda.cu` file is exporting a c linkable entry point to that function.

I was able to rectify the issue you describe by modifying the include sequence in your `main.c` to match what you are doing elsewhere:

```
#include "../include/mylib_omp.h"
extern "C"{
#include "../include/mylib_cuda.h"
}
```

There's more than one way to accomplish this, however.  Since you are explicitly specifying to `nvcc` that the files in question are to be compiled as c++ source (`-x c++`) I'm not sure there is any need to export anything as c-linkable.  You should be able to discard all your `extern "C"` decorations and achieve the same result.  The C++ linking will fix everything up.

As an aside, I'm not sure it makes sense to pass the `-x c++` switch to `nvcc` when you are compiling your `.cu` file.  I think this is working due to the fact that you have no actual device code in your `mylib_cuda.cu` file, just a CUDA API call (which is legitimate even in a C++ file).  If you actually put device code in that file (e.g. kernel functions) I think you will have trouble with the `-x c++` switch on that file.  You may wish to refer to the `nvcc` [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#file-and-path-specifications).

Comment: Great! Thank you. This fixed at least this error. Now I am stuck with something else I never ever encountered. I removed all the "extern" stuff and the "-x c++" option. Nothing else changed. But now I get the following error via make:
`nvcc -arch=sm_12 -ccbin=g++-4.4 -Xcompiler -openmp -I include -I/opt/cuda/include -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -c -o sources/mylib_cuda.o sources/mylib_cuda.cu
cc1plus: Fehler: Ausgabedatei doppelt angegeben
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'sources/mylib_cuda.o' failed
make: *** [sources/mylib_cuda.o] Error 1`
Any notes on that one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For `gcc` or `g++` I don't think `-openmp` is a [valid compile switch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/Enabling-OpenMP.html).  Try `-fopenmp` instead.

Comment: after som further googling I found two options '-fopenmp lgomp' but now the old error is back and some more :(
'sources/main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `myfunc_CUDA'
sources/mylib_omp.o: In function `myfunc_OMP':
mylib_omp.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_start'
mylib_omp.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_end'
sources/mylib_omp.o: In function `myfunc_OMP.omp_fn.0':
mylib_omp.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
mylib_omp.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num''

Comment: This is not the old error.  During compiling you need `-fopenmp`.  During linking you need `-lgomp` not `lgomp`  The issue you are facing now is due to lack of `-lgomp`

Comment: thanks for your patience! I think when it comes to the 'omp' part I got it now. with "same error" I was referring to the very first line of the make output where it complains about 'undefined reference to myfunc_CUDA' which indeed is the original error which still persists.

Comment: If you removed the `-x g++` *entirely* then things will be broken again, as your `.c` files will be compiled with c linkage, but your `.cu` file will be compiled with c++ linkage.  Can you just change all your .c files to .cpp ? That should fix the linkage error (again).  Or else modify the `Makefile` so that `-x g++` is specified for .c files but not for .cu files.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you SO much! Really really great! Now everything works and I am some more bits of wisdom richer!